Wann benutzt man "es" im Deutschen?
Wann benutzt man "es" im Deutschen? Zum Beispiel, ist es korrekt zu sagen:

Was ist das? 
Es ist ein Buch. 
Es ist eine Wand.

Oder sollte man sagen:

Wer ist das? 
Es ist Anna Brown.


Ist das Anna Brown?
Nein, das ist nicht Anna Brown, es ist Emma Brown.


Bei den Antworten auf "Was/wer ist das?" benutzt man üblicherweise auch "das":

Was ist das? - Das ist ein Buch.
Wer ist das? - Das ist Anna.

"Es" benutzt man genau so wie "er" oder "sie".

Was ist das? - Das ist ein Buch. Es ist sehr alt.
Wer ist das? - Das ist Anna. Sie studiert Deutsch und Geschichte.
Was ist das? - Das ist ein Baum. Er verliert gerade seine Blätter.

Daneben gibt es noch die Verwendung als unpersönliches Es wie in "Es regnet." und anderen Varianten.

Verstehe, also, es ist falsch "es" wie in meinen Sätzen zu benutzen.

@EminbayliMuhammad es ist nicht falsch, aber eher ungewöhnlich (darum auch "üblicherweise" in dieser Antwort. Für besonderen Effekt kann man davon Ausnahmen machen.

@planetmaker und könntest du mir bitte sagen, gibt es irgendeinen Unterschied in der Bedeutung?

I don't think so. Yet the usage example of this answer illustrates the common usage and contextual distinction quite well, when using 'das', and when using 'es'.

... ein Buch. Es ist... . Hier bezieht sich 'es' auf das Nomen, das neutrum ist.
... ein Baum. Er verliert ... . Und hier bezieht sich 'er' auf das Nomen, das maskulin ist.
Aber:
"Es ist Emma Brown." oder "Es ist eine Wand." Ich verstehe nicht, worauf sich 'es' hier bezieht, da 'Wand' feminin ist. @planetmaker

It refers to the same thing the "das" in its place would refer to: something mentioned earlier.

Es ist ein Personalpronomen. Damit bezieht sich der Sprecher auf etwas, das vorher erwähnt wurde oder das später erwähnt wird. Manchmal ist es auch nur ein bloßer Platzhalter, damit der Satz ein (formales) Subjekt hat.
Das ist hier ein Demonstrativpronomen (nicht zu verwechseln mit das als Artikel). Damit bezieht sich der Sprecher auf etwas, das unmittelbar vorher erwähnt wurde.
Zum Beispiel:

Der Raum muss mindestens drei Mal am Tag gelüftet werden. Ich habe dir das schon zehn Mal gesagt.

Hier wäre Ich habe es dir schon zehn Mal gesagt nicht völlig falsch, aber wegen der Bezugnahme auf den unmittelbar vorangehenden Satz ist das angebrachter.
Es trägt üblicherweise keine besondere Betonung und wird als Objekt nicht ins Vorfeld gestellt. Daher wäre Es habe ich dir zehn Mal gesagt falsch, wohingegen Das habe ich dir zehn Mal gesagt vollkommen korrekt ist.
